# How do I find out where my server is?

Tags: web-hosting, images, server, cdn, geolocation

I have this image hosted through Dropbox and it loads slowly. I need to determine if the location of the server is too far away from my main audience so I can determine if that is the cause of the performance issue.

Comment: Dropbox is not a CDN. There is no consideration for performance for serving of content for a website.

Comment: Can you add an anonymous example of the link to your image? Just in case.

Comment: Dropbox is never meant to be a hosting service, instead you could use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), you'll get 1 year for free. Or you could use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get IP that serves image with ping command or in Developer Tools of your browser

[image]

And check it's possible destination in [geoiptool](http://www.geoiptool.com/) but the best solution to check you page speed is to test it with [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) or [gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/), cause distance is not always important. Anyway Dropbox is definitely not for storing images.

Comment: In addition, http://network-tools.com can look it up based on domain name or url and tell you more detailed stats about routing, DNS, traces, hops, etc.